# Add SQL Server as a data source in Azure Data Lake Analytics

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake

I'm doing some tests with Azure Data Lake Analytics and I can’t add a new SQL Server database as a Data Source. When I click on "Add data source", the only two available options are: "Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1" and "Azure Storage".

What I want is to add one SQL Server database so that I can run U-SQL queries against it.

Our SQL Server firewall is [correctly configured](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/u-sql/create-data-source-u-sql)  to allow access to Azure Services, but I am not allowed to add it as a data source.

How can this be done? Is it a matter of other configuration issues?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by not allowed to add it ? do you seeing any error ? describe it

Comment: @Jayendran I mean that there are no errors, just that I have only these two options to choose. So I cannot choose to add a SQL Server instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my research ,there is no other configuration issues for sql server data source in DLA. Based on this official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-portal#manage-data-sources), DLA only supports two data sources:Data Lake Store and Azure Storage.

As workaround , I suggest you using [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/) to transfer data from [sql server database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-sql-server) to [azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage) so that you could run U-SQL script against data source.

Any concern,please let me know.